# Output object in template (Object.entries)

Tags: sveltekit

I am trying to output an object in a Sveltekit template.

This works great, but not so flexible:

```
{#each Object.entries(cdi.data[0][0]) as [key, value], index (key)}
    <li>{key} - {value}</li>
{/each}


{#each Object.entries(cdi.data[0][1]) as [key, value], index (key)}
    <li>{key} - {value}</li>
{/each}
```

I would like all the items to be output automatically, something like:

```
{#each Object.entries(cdi.data[0]) as item, i (i)}
    {#each Object.entries(item[i]) as [key, value], index (index)}
      {key} {value}
    {/each}
{/each}
```

But I cannot figure it out, any ideas?

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
            {#each cdi.data[0] as item, i (i)}
                {#each Object.entries(item) as [key, value], index (index)}
                    {key} {value}
                {/each}
            {/each}
```